# Keras neural network with multiple loss functions

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I am trying to make a neural network that will have different loss function for different outputs. For example, a part of my output is probabilities formed using softmax, so I want to use categorical loss for that part of the output. In order to do so, I am doing this:

```
model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[out1,out2])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss =['categorical_crossentropy','mse'],loss_weights=[1,1])
```

When I fit the model

```
history = model.fit(x = Xtrain,y=[ytrain1,ytrain2],batch_size=28, epochs=20,verbose=2)
```

I get this error:
ValueError: Creating variables on a non-first call to a function decorated with tf.function.
What can be the reason for this?

Comment: does it work when you remove 'categorical_crossentropy' along with the weights?

Comment: Got my issue. I was actually also using binary crossentropy along with tye losses I mentioned in the question. Weird though, but removing binary crossentropy solved the problem. I kind of got the idea from you, so thanks!